# How can panels be made waterproof for exterior use?

Tags: water-protection, panel

There are many situations where a paneled construction would be desired for an exterior use. For example, a well-made door has recessed panels that are mortised together, but obviously if the panels can move in their mortise then there is crack that water can enter.

I had a similar problem with a light block. The light block is made from a beveled casing that is mitered together with splines like a picture frame and a panel of wood, about 8" square, is tenoned into the casing. The light fixture mounts through the floating panel. It looks like this:

[image]

We made a number of these lightblocks and painted them with a heavy duty oil paint. The tops of the blocks are flashed in copper. All of them are fine except one with experiences a lot of moisture because water runs off of the roof in such a way that it washes over the light block in a heavy rain.

What apparently happened is that water went into the crack between the casing and the inner panel, the lower rail of the casing got wet, expanded and then cracked out of its miters.

One possibility is that the mortise is defective somehow. In other words, the panel mortise is only about 3/8" deep, so theoretically the water could only get into this limited area. However, if the casing was not fitted perfectly, then water could have seeped into the miters themselves, and that might have caused enough absorbtion to produce the split.

One possible approach would be to epoxy or paint the inside of the panel mortises to try to make the slot waterproof before assembling the frame.

(Note that trying to make the whole thing out of one piece of wood is not feasible due to the size of the light block and other factors.)

Now that I think about it, maybe what should have been done was not to mortise it on the bottom, only on the top and the two sides. The bottom of the panel could then sit on a rabetted drip ledge.

Is there a standard approach to this problem? (For example, as used on exterior door panels.)

Comment: I'm not sure why you got a down vote, but I think you've answered your own question: "All of them are fine except one with experiences a lot of moisture because water runs off of the roof in such a way that it washes over the light block in a heavy rain." If your wooden front door, built exactly the same, were to be directly exposed to heavy rain, it would deteriorate in the same way and at a similar rate. The solution, I'd suggest, is to improve the weather protection at this one site, then put up a new one built & finished exactly like the others.

Comment: Fresh water especially is not healthy for woodwork. You might want to research how boats are fitted and fixtured.

Answer (score 5):

I don't have anything specific to say about your design, other than to offer general recommendations for anything trimmed with wood that has to handle the weather. My bona fides aren't particularly extensive, but I have worked in the trades in my early life, so take what I say with a grain of plaster.

Standing fresh water or long terms of damp is what rots out both boats and houses. It sticks to edges and can creep into voids against the pull of gravity. It can freeze and thaw several times a day creating its own voids for eventual egress.

Water will seek out any void and pool in any flat or concave surface. Even if the other fixtures haven't leaked yet, they will eventually when you get the right weather, or as the finish ages.

Flashing the top with a drip edge is a good idea, but you have to make sure the flashing doesn't allow water underneath. Drip edges are also where water can creep underneath if the drip edge isn't generous enough. You may have to flash the flashing to be sure we are directing that weather away as much as possible. If you don't want flashing, or it isn't convenient, it used to be common for carpenters to break the edge face of trim with a groove to help break the surface tension of water to allow it to drip and not just follow the surface.

All top surfaces should have a generous angle on them so water doesn't pool. Flat surfaces are just not going to last. The idea is to assume buckets of water will hit your surfaces and you want it to roll off as quickly as possible. The tops of all outdoor fixtures should ideally be like little roofs.

To this end, you always assume some water egress, and the key is defence in depth. This usually means you deliberately leave ways for water to flow out at the bottom. Similar to brickwork with slots at the bottom row to let out water that makes it through the brick on the top, many wooden fixtures meant for handling the weather will have ways for water to exit at the lower edges. There should be an easy path for water to find theses exits without pooling or seeking egress deeper into the building structure. If you are serious about it, you will have multiple layers of waterproofing separate from each-other, each with their own way of allowing water to escape.

Defence in depth means your example of a traditionally panelled door wouldn't necessarily be exposed to direct weather. This is why storm doors were often necessary, though mostly to protect the finish. The panels are inset into a frame which allows water to roll off, but the seam is fitted so that the wood can swell a bit. That, and the varnish is sufficient for keeping out water. But panelled doors are not, and never will be, waterproof. With help from overhangs, porches, storm doors, and some carpentry design, they can shed reasonable amounts of water. Fixtures placed outside the home in less sheltered areas need different ways of managing weather.

Because the absolutely worse waterproofing is the sort that *appears* to work, but actually lets water creep inside the structure over years, leading to the sort of damage that results in insurance claims and complete rebuilds. It's better to have that trimmed exterior leak like crazy and rot itself out than silently let water in over years.

Finally, wood exposed to the elements will need to be refinished regularly. It may be an unpopular opinion, but even the best and most modern finish will only delay refinishing when exposed to the raw elements. For this reason I'd choose a finish and a design that is easy to refinish.

Alternatively, you go the route that has worked for a long time: choose a naturally weather resistant wood and use it as a sort of simple "roofing" and "siding" over your exposed fixtures. This is a specific look that you may not want, but it has so many advantages that it has to be mentioned.